# getting started with processing data with python

Tags: python, excel, vba

i have an excel spreadsheet of about 3 million cells. i asked the following question and i liked the answer about saving the spreadsheet as CSV and then processing it with python:

[solution to perform lots of calculations on 3 million data points and make charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322939/solution-to-perform-lots-of-calculations-on-3-million-data-points-and-make-charts/3323168#3323168)

1. is there a library that i can use that will read the csv into a matrix or should i write one myself?
2. does python speak with VBA at all?
3. after i am done processing the data, is it simple to put it back in the form of a CSV so that i can open it in excel for viewing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [solution to perform lots of calculations on 3 million data points and make charts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322939/solution-to-perform-lots-of-calculations-on-3-million-data-points-and-make-charts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a library that i can use that will read the csv into a matrix or should i write one myself?

The `csv` module handles just about everything you could want.

> does python speak with VBA at all?

Iron Python might.

> after i am done processing the data, is it simple to put it back in the form of a CSV so that i can open it in excel for viewing?

The `csv` module handles just about everything you could want.

Suggestion: Read this: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Answer (score 3):

I like NumPy's [loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt) for this sort of thing.  Very configurable for reading CSVs.  And [savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt) for putting it back after manipulation.  Or you could check out the built in [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-csv) module if you'd rather not install anything new.

Answer (score 1):

If we speak pythonish, why not to use http://www.python-excel.org/ ?

Example of read file:

```
import xlrd
rb = xlrd.open_workbook('file.xls',formatting_info=True)
sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
  row = sheet.row_values(rownum)
  for c_el in row:
    print c_el
```

Writing the new file:

```
import xlwt
from datetime import datetime

font0 = xlwt.Font()
font0.name = 'Times New Roman'
font0.colour_index = 2
font0.bold = True

style0 = xlwt.XFStyle()
style0.font = font0

style1 = xlwt.XFStyle()
style1.num_format_str = 'D-MMM-YY'

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('A Test Sheet')

ws.write(0, 0, 'Test', style0)
ws.write(1, 0, datetime.now(), style1)
ws.write(2, 0, 1)
ws.write(2, 1, 1)
ws.write(2, 2, xlwt.Formula("A3+B3"))

wb.save('example.xls')
```

There are other examples on the page.

Comment: Using `easyxf` is ummm easier. E.g. `style0 = xlwt.easyxf("font: name Times New Roman, colour red, bold true"); style1 = xlwt.easyxf(num_format_str="d-mmm-yyyy")`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to deal with changing back and forth from CSV you can use win32com, which can be downloaded here. http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/Downloads.html